# Ghostscript Pdf Transparant Objects Removal

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript, acrobat, postscript

I have several .pdf containing reoccuring transparent objects (text).
(It has non transparant objects (text and vectors) as well as images)

*Not watermarks made by Acrobat or others.* **It is in the background as styling.**

To removing them manualy these is **impossible**, since the content on the pdf pages is mixed with the text on the page (grouping).

Is there a way to **alter** the **opacity** of translucent objects to **0**. Or even **removing** **them** completely from the pdf, with ghostscript?
*Using adobe acrobat pre-flight, and moving them as images, removes all of the images in the pdf, instead of only the transparent objects.*

- **How can this be achieved with the help of Ghostscript and the
  appropriate PostScript code?**

These Awnsers

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/29657475/9921462
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/37858893/9921462

Where helpful, to know how to get objects and images, but not filtering specifically for transparent objects.

Any ideas are appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the reason you can't remove the objects using Acrobat is not because they are transparent. Its much more likely that they are described by a Form XObject. Those can't normally be edited by Acrobat.

You can use -dNOTRANSPARENCY and the pdfwrite device to produce a new PDF file with no transparency, but that will eliminate **all** the transparency in the output file.

Fundamentally there's no real way to do what you want, other than by manually editing the PDF file in an editor. You should go back to the original document and do the work there. PDF is not intended as an editable format.

Comment: You can remove the object in Acrobat manualy. But since there where used as spacing between other objects or text (They are not grouped correctly). They mess up the layout when doing so.

The -dNOTRANSPARENCY  option does indeed removes the transparency, by setting the opacity to 1. But is not really useful.
Something that changes the transparency from all abject that have an opacity less then 1 to 0 could be a solution.

Comment: Using the -dNOTRANSPARENCY  did change the selecting of the use to be transparent objects to same group. Now I can remove it manually much easier. Though not automatically. Any ideas to search and delete the object or object group? (Or should I make a new question?)

Comment: No, not really, Ghostscripr isn't designed to be an editor, it has no user interface to speak of.