# Ghostscript Version issue to remove all images from a PDF?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

[Kurt Pfeifle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657335/how-can-i-remove-all-images-from-a-pdf) answered fantastically on the question [How can I remove all images from a PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657335/how-can-i-remove-all-images-from-a-pdf).

I have Ghostscript Version 8.71 installed.  Unfortunately, I am unable to run any of the command listed below.

gs -o onlyTXT.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFILTERVECTOR -dFILTERIMAGE input.pdf

gs -o onlyIMG.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFILTERVECTOR -dFILTERTEXT  input.pdf

gs -o onlyVCT.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFILTERIMAGE  -dFILTERTEXT  input.pdf

Is version not supporting or anywhere I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade. The feature you are trying to use there will not work on such an old (8 years old) version of Ghostscript.

The feature you are trying to use was implemented a bit over three years ago. Its listed as a new feature in the release notes for version 9.18. so you need to upgrade to at least that version, possibly later. You should upgrade to the current version anyway to get a load of security fixes.